# Extracting hyperlink from HTML table with rvest

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, href, rvest

I've seen similar questions here and implemented the solutions but still can't seem to figure this one out. Still an R novice, so bear with me: I've managed to to get a table of Barack Obama's speeches from [this website](http://www.americanrhetoric.com/barackobamaspeeches.htm) using rvest:

```
library(rvest)
page <- read_html("http://www.americanrhetoric.com/barackobamaspeeches.htm")
speeches <- page %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="AutoNumber1"]') %>% 
  html_table(fill=TRUE)
speeches <- speeches[[1]][,2:4]
head(speeches)
```

which yields:

```
            X2                                            X3    X4
1             <NA>                                          <NA>  <NA>
2    Delivery Date                  Speech Title/Text/MultiMedia Audio
3     27 July 2004 Democratic National Convention Keynote Speech   mp3
4  06 January 2005 Senate Speech on Ohio Electoral Vote Counting   mp3
5     04 June 2005              Knox College Commencement Speech   mp3
6 15 December 2005              Senate Speech on the PATRIOT Act   mp3
```

However, I'd like to also extract the hyperlink for each entry in the "Speech" column, which naturally lives in the `href` attribute. I've researched this pretty thoroughly online, and some people say to also specify the html attribute with `html_attr('href')`, but if I include that in the above code I get this error:

`Error in UseMethod("xml_attr") : no applicable method for 'xml_attr' applied to an object of class "list"`

Another person suggesting tinkering with the actual function with `trace` but that seems overly involved for something that seems kind of straightforward. Any idea where I'm tripping up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [Selector Gadget](http://selectorgadget.com/) to determine the node, I extracted the URLs with:

```
page %>% html_nodes("td:nth-child(2) a") %>% html_attr("href")
```

Comment: Wow such a simple fix. Thanks so much! Is there a reason the XPath won't work in this situation?

Comment: I think it's because the XPath `id="AutoNumber1"` doesn't have an `href` attribute.